# Is the ARM instruction set the same for all ARM processors?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Is the ARM instruction the same on all ARM processors? Or just a subset of it is mandatory and universal?

For instance, when Apple was designing the Mac silicon, could they have modified the instruction set to add or remove instructions? For example, if a code runs on an ARM Cortex-A76, would it also run on the Mac silicon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not the same on all ARM processors. When AArch64 appeared, the new base instruction set was developed, called A64. It designated the version "ARMv8" (and now, ARMv9) and stands quite aside. This ISA is used in highest performance modern processors, including Apple's M1.

Instruction set of other versions evolved, but the in general it shares the same idea. For example, the very first version did not have a hardware multiply instruction.

Don't get lost in those versions, as processor developed in ARM sometimes happened to use confusing notation; ARM7TDMI uses ARMv4 ISA.

Notable evolutionary step was some standard extensions, for instance Jazelle set to run Java byte code, and Neon set of SIMD operations. Co-processors can add their own additional instructions.

In addition to this, additional *encodings* of the command set appeared starting from the version ARMv4, which are called Thumb and Thumb-2. They drop some features and instructions but achieve tighter code packing, reducing size of each instruction from 32 bit to 16 bit (despite the fact some things could require more than one Thumb instructions). One of features removed is 4-bit predication field for all commands except branching. Some small cores (Cortex-M) now *only* support this Thumb encoding, for example, the famous Blue Pill (STM32F103C8T6 MCU based on the Cortex-M3 core, which implements an ARMv7-based ISA).

Having said that, you can be sure that same base commands exists on all processors, like ADD in the Cortex-M family is the same thing as in the Cortex-R and Cortex-A (and has the same binary coding in same version of the instruction set, currently ARMv7, subject to the selected coding scheme).

Therefore, you can compile the package once for the particular ISA version and use it on all processors of that architecture; the example of that use is how [OpenWRT packages](https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.4/packages/) are distributed. Regarding your question: while M1 should be able to handle Cortex-A76 instructions, this doesn't mean that the software will run, because it likely expects different environment than MacOS, including things like memory configuration, the system calling conventions and the like. But if you have, say, a native Linux binary that worked on A76 and [run Linux natively on M1](https://asahilinux.org/), the same binary will run on it.